# Receiving Serial data from windows PC

Tags: serial-port, minicom

I am attempting to send a string of serial data from a windows PC using Powershell to a linux machine, I have managed to prove that the data reaches the last point before being connected onto the linux machine.
as I am fairly new to the Linux and Ubuntu operating system i was hoping to get some help to show me how i can receive that serial data on a linux machine and begin to log it onto a text file. The serial data being sent from a windows PC using standard RS232 connection. I read some forums that stated I could use 'minicom' to display the received serial data but I have not managed to have any luck with that.

Can you please help?

Comment: Thanks for that, my data is now being received by the linux system!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page example how to use minicom](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/connect-soekris-single-board-computer-using-minicom.html)

**Install minicom**

```
sudo apt-get install minicom
```

**Display Detected System’s Serial Support**

```
dmesg | grep tty

Output will be something like:
[   37.531286] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[   37.531841] 00:0b: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[   37.532138] 0000:04:00.3: ttyS1 at I/O 0x1020 (irq = 18) is a 16550A
```

**setserial command**

setserial is a program designed to set and/or report the configuration information associated with a serial port. This information includes what I/O port and IRQ a particular serial port is using, and whether or not the break key should be interpreted as the Secure Attention Key, and so on. Just type the following command:

```
setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123]
```

Output:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x1020, IRQ: 18
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

setserial with -g option help to find out what physical serial ports your Linux box has.

**Setup minicom**

The -s option use to setup minicom. Type the following command at shell prompt:

```
minicom -s
```

**Start minicom**

```
minicom
```

**Configure serial port**

You need to configure serial port. Use up and down arrows to select menus. Press down and select Serial port setup:

**minicom in action**

You need to connect your serial device usingcable. Once connected power on device and type minicom command without -s option:

```
minicom -c on
```